# PostgreSQL Array inside a JSON object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Im trying to build a custom json, from two tables with left join on a PostgreSQL function, but cant it working.

Table Structure:

**post**

```
 id | title | description
```

**postPhoto**

```
 id | postId (FK) | name
```

json example:

```
{
    postId: 1,
    title: ''
    description: '',
    postPhotos: [
        {id: 1, name: 'photo1.png'},
        {id: 1, name: 'photo2.png'},
    ]
}
```

SQL Function:

```
$BODY$DECLARE
    success boolean;
    msg text;
    var_most_recent json;
BEGIN


SELECT to_json(array_agg(t)) INTO var_most_recent FROM (

    SELECT *
        ( SELECT to_json(array_agg(t)) FROM (
                SELECT * FROM postPhoto AS PP WHERE post.id = PP."postId"
            )t )
    FROM post
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10

)t;

success = TRUE; msg = 'Successfully Returned Post data';
RETURN (SELECT json_build_object(
    'success', success,
    'msg', msg,
    'body', json_build_object(
        'mostRecent', var_most_recent
    )
));

END;$BODY$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the `json_agg` aggregate function. Here's how I would do it:

```
SELECT json_agg(p)
FROM
   (SELECT
        json_build_object(
            'postId', post.id,
            'title', post.title,
            'description', post.description,
            'postPhotos',
                (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id',id,'name',name))
                 FROM postPhoto WHERE postId=post.id)
        ) AS p
    FROM post
    ORDER BY post.id
    LIMIT 10) as t
WHERE json_array_length(p->'postPhotos')>1;
```

Comment: This works but i need to wrap multiple posts in an array, cause i dont have a where i have a LIMIT by 10 so the json would look like this: 
http://pastebin.com/W3MSm8fh

Comment: No problem, we can just wrap it in another `SELECT` query, see my updated answer.

Comment: Can you help me out to select post where postphoto is not null

Comment: @JasminMiftari What can be null exactly?

Comment: So for the moment, i select all posts with their postPhotos, but i want to select all posts where postPhotos count > 1.
Select post which countain postPhotos ( or contain rows in postPhoto )

Comment: @JasminMiftari I added a `WHERE` clause in the outer query to filter out post that have 0 or 1 photos.